# R: Looping through data frame summing row values

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like the following:

```
team playername points
team1 player1     80
team1 player2     40
...
team2 player1     98
...
team20 player1    40
```

It has 3 columns, the team name, player name, and the total points that player has scored. What I want to do is loop through the data frame and calculate the sum on a per team basis. So team1's total points would be 120 in the following example. I wrote some test code earlier to try to get some output:

```
curTeam = ""
count = 0
for (i in df) {
    if (curTeam == i$Team) {
        count = count + i$points
    } else {
        print (count)
        curTeam = i$Team
        count = i$points
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

> $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Is there a better way  to do what I'm trying to do?

Thanks.

Comment: `xtabs(points ~ team, df)` should do it.  Also see `?aggregate`.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the luxury of programming in RStudio so I don't have access to the help functions or the ability to see the objects that were created. Does xtabs return a list? Would it be possible to throw this information into a bar char?

Comment: You can't see the results and you have no help files?  What platform are you using?

Comment: Just type `?aggregate` and a help file will pop up, one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
df <- read.table(text = "team playername points
team1 player1     80
team1 player2     40
team2 player1     98
team20 player1    40", header = TRUE)

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(team) %>% summarise(sum(points))
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit what you are doing in the last statement? Not familiar with the %>%

Comment: @AlexCauthen `df %>% group_by(team)` is equivalent to writing `group_by(df, team)`.